# How should i check for time and date attendance in python

Tags: python, datetime, icalendar

I am working on this project that uses a hardware to take fingerprints of students. I am stuck in the middle of developing a counter for checking attendance.

Example:
What I have now is the time stamp data for a student (logged from the hardware) that is stored in a list shown below

> ['2018-02-26 12:58:10', '2018-02-27 15:08:07']

And I want to implement a counter to check whether it matches the time stamp using individual ical file for each student.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180226T130000Z
DTEND:20180226T140000Z
SUMMARY:LECTURE 
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180227T140000Z
DTEND:20180227T150000Z
SUMMARY:Practical
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180227T150000Z
DTEND:20180227T160000Z
SUMMARY:LECTURE
END:VEVENT
```

I am currently using ics (Python icalendar (rfc5545) parser) which gives me a list of all the events in the icalendar file.
So for this case the student missed one class as it is not being logged which is the class for the practical and will count 2 out of 3 attended classes.

It will be grateful if i can get some feedback on how should I proceed this or is there more efficient way to do this as this is as far as I can think of.

Comment: Two questions: timestamp data spans 2 days (February 26th and 27th) - it is an error in the example, I presume? Also, every VEVENT starts in 2018 and ends in 2017…

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake! I just changed the dates so its easier to understand.

Comment: Timestamps still span 2 days, so based on this student spent a night at school ;) Regardless - you could simply merge events from fingerprint timestamps and ical (preserving order on time) and iterate over them, counting each class that starts and ends.